# 1) pip3 install matplotlib error then 2) pip cannot import main

Tags: python, pip

I typed `pip3 install matplotlib` but got the error below.

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/d1/7b12cd79c791348cb0c78ce6e7d16bd72992f13c9f1e8e43d2725a6d8adf/matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Beginning with Matplotlib 3.1, Python 3.6 or above is required.

    This may be due to an out of date pip.

    Make sure you have pip >= 9.0.1.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mf5yly3l/matplotlib/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Then I tried upgrading `pip install --upgrade pip` but running pip3 install matplotlib now gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use python3 -m pip install instead of pip install

```
sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip
--reinstall
```